# Android make video from images

Tags: android, video, android-ndk

I am able to create video for one image using below code but unable to know how to convert multiple images to video file in android(i am using NDK-videokit.so file, there is no problem using this)

```
String[] arrayOfString2 = new String[12];
      arrayOfString2[0] = "ffmpeg";
      arrayOfString2[1] = "-r";
      arrayOfString2[2] = ("1/" + VideomakerMain.this.usersec);
      arrayOfString2[3] = "-i";
      arrayOfString2[4] = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Test/5.png");
      arrayOfString2[5] = "-c:v";
      arrayOfString2[6] = "libx264";
      arrayOfString2[7] = "-r";
      arrayOfString2[8] = "2";
      arrayOfString2[9] = "-pix_fmt";
      arrayOfString2[10] = "yuv420p";
      arrayOfString2[11] = VideomakerMain.this.videoname;
      Videokit localVideokit = new Videokit();

        localVideokit.run(arrayOfString1, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Test";
```

any one have idea how to make video from multiple images?

Comment: Use ffmpeg jar for that purpose.

Comment: can you provide path and sample.

Comment: Try this link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android

Comment: There is no example that help me to solve my problem

Comment: ok then, you can take hint from this link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395136/create-a-video-file-from-images-using-ffmpeg