# Video generator from images in android

Tags: android

I am making an video creator app in which i will select some images and make video from images and add background music.how is it possible, is there any demo available. i found many time but not getting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using ffmpeg. See this post for an example in how to use ffmpeg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10412116/2116716

Here is a sample application that you may be able to start from: 
https://github.com/jdpxiaoming/Android-FFmpeg-Images-Video

Comment: If this answered your question you can click the ✓ to the left of my answer.